# Android C++ new operator leads to "malloc(4294967295) failed, errno 12"

Tags: android, c++, gradle, malloc, sdl

## TD;DR

I'm porting a C++ project of mine to android, but when using the `new` operator it actually calls `malloc(4294967295)` for some reason, which results in an out of memory error, even though debugging proved my classes to be of a correct size (and the project works when built for Windows).

This results in the app getting stuck on a black screen on physical android devices, or to simply crash on emulators

## Context

I am currently trying to port an [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) project of mine to android.

For this, I followed the instructions from [the tutorial located in the official SDL repo](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.5/docs/README-android.md).
Additionally, I followed [this tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/53_extensions_and_changing_orientation/android_windows/index.php) to add the SDL_image module to my project, along with SDL_ttf.

## The issue

Building the app works fine, but once booted, it gets stuck to a black screen:

[image: Screenshot of what the app looks like when booted]

## Figuring out why it happens (debugging)

### "Print" debugging

So I have plugged my phone into my computer and tried to debug the issue with [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb), using prints, and here is what I have found:

To initialize SDL and other components, my game's `main` function looks as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG", "Starting");
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int targetFPS = 60;
    const int frameDelay = 1000 / targetFPS;

    // Init
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG", "Constructing Game class of size: %lX", sizeof(Game));
    Game* game = new Game(argc, argv);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG", "Game constructed");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG", "Initializing");
    int errInit = game->init("SAE201205", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG", "Initialized: %d", errInit);

    if (errInit == 0) {
        while (game->running()) {
            /* Game Logic here */
        }

        game->clean();
    }

    delete game;


    return 0;
}
```

Notice the `__android_log_print` calls, they are here to help debugging the function.

When booting the app on my phone and catching my phone's logs using `adb logcat`, the following lines can be seen:

```
06-14 08:34:35.471  8262  8326 V SDL     : Running main function SDL_main from library /data/app/~~F1pn5U_H13LZFzCic5LLyA==/org.libsdl.app-AHd89RMgz8bystTw8XwclA==/lib/arm/libmain.so
06-14 08:34:35.471  8262  8326 V SDL     : nativeRunMain()
06-14 08:34:35.471  8262  8326 D DEBUG   : Starting
06-14 08:34:35.471  8262  8326 D DEBUG   : Constructing Game class of size: 98
06-14 08:34:35.472  8262  8326 W libc    : malloc(4294967295) failed: returning null pointer, errno: 12
```

And then the application breaks. Further prints I have written never get printed.

As can be seen, when using the new operator, it calls `malloc`. Problem is, instead of calling it with the size of my Game class (0x98, as printed above), it calls it with a size of 4294967295 (=0xFFFFFFFF, or -1 if signed), therefore resulting in malloc throwing error 12 ("Out of memory").

This makes absolutely no sense, since I am obviously not trying to allocate 4 GB of memory, and since the size of my Game class is correctly computed by the compiler when printed, it should try to allocate the correct size.

### Disassembling

To make sure that the new operator was indeed called, I opened the compiled `.so` file containing my code in Ghidra.
The instructions corresponding to what we are interested it are as follows:

[image: Ghidra screenshot of the relevant instructions]
As can be seen, the new operator is indeed called. It is linked to an external function (since it's a shared library build), but there's no trace of a wrong malloc.

However, the allocated size passed into the new operator seems to be `0x108` instead of the printed `0x98`. It is likely that the size Ghidra shows is the correct one, since the android print format seems to have problems inrelated to the described issue here (when using `%X`, the compiler warns and asks to use `%lX`, but when using `%lX`it warns and asks to use `%X`).

My Windows build gives a size of `0x130`. My theory on that size difference is that pointer size, as well as other native structures, might be different.

Either way, no matter the correct size, it is far from being `0xFFFFFFFF`, so the malloc error is unlikely related to the size difference.

## My configuration

Here is how my project is configured.

First off, it is a Gradle project following [the same structure as in the official SDL repo](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/tree/release-2.26.5/android-project):

[image: Screenshot of the project's root folder]

My app's `Application.mk` file ([here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.5/android-project/app/jni/Application.mk)) is as follows:

```
    # Uncomment this if you're using STL in your project
    # You can find more information here:
    # https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support
    APP_STL := c++_shared

    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64

    # Min runtime API level
    APP_PLATFORM=android-16
```

As can be seen, I uncommented the `APP_STL` line because my project uses a lot of STL functions. It is set to `c++_shared` by default, but I have tried `c++_static` and faced the same results. Additionally, `gnustl_shared` and `gnustl_static` are deprecated and do not work with SDL projects anyway.

The `CMakeLists.txt` file located in the same folder ([here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.5/android-project/app/jni/CMakeLists.txt)) is as follows:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

    project(GAME)

    # armeabi-v7a requires cpufeatures library
    # include(AndroidNdkModules)
    # android_ndk_import_module_cpufeatures()


    # SDL sources are in a subfolder named "SDL"
    add_subdirectory(SDL)

    # Compilation of companion libraries
    add_subdirectory(SDL_image)
    #add_subdirectory(SDL_mixer)
    add_subdirectory(SDL_ttf)

    # Your game and its CMakeLists.txt are in a subfolder named "src"
    add_subdirectory(src)
```

The `Android.mk` file located in my project's C++ source folder ([here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.5/android-project/app/jni/src/Android.mk)) is as follows:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := main

    SDL_PATH := ../SDL

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL_image/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL_ttf/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include

    # Add your application source files here...
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp <all my other cpp files here, irrelevant so not including them>

    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_ttf

    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -lOpenSLES -llog -landroid

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I didn't edit any other configuration file as far as I remember (and checked). Feel free to ask if you need the content of a specific file I didn't include here.

## Where am I with it now

This kind of problem is just so specific it that it is hard to find anyone who met any error close to this one, so I didn't find anything

As a reminder, the project compiles and works for Windows, the issue I'm encountering here is android-exclusive.

If I can theorize, I'd say that the c++ library simply has an option that I missed to support the `new` operator, but I couldn't find anything and I'm very new to android development, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: What is the `Game` class constructor doing? It seems the allocation is happening inside it. Please create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: The Game class constructor initializes other components, But considering the thrown error mentions memory allocation, it is veyr likely to be the allocation part and not the class construction itself. However, I will look into it and see it it may not come from another component and will tell here. I'll work on a minimal reproducible example when I have more time, will post it here once that's done.

Comment: Even if you're not explicitly allocating memory in your class constructor there could be other reasons for these allocations taking place -- e.g containers such as `std::vector` etc. being initialized.

Comment: @RedStoneMatt You have demonstrated that the allocation that is failing is not the allocation of Game, That the Game constructor is at fault is the obvious next possibility.

Comment: @RedStoneMatt Anyway there is an easy test to make, replace `Game* game = new Game(argc, argv);` with `Game game(argc, argv);`. (You'll need to change the rest of `main` since `game` is no longer a pointer, but that's trivial). There is no obvious need to allocate the Game object and If you still have a crash that proves its the constuctor.

Comment: I did not think of it this way, I'll give it a try and keep you guys updated, Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Doesn't logcat provide you with a backtrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

As commenters pointed out, the constructor of the Game class was at fault, not the memory allocation itself.

I thought I had removed everything that could lead to a crash in it, but that was without knowing that members of the class get constructed even if it isn't explicitely stated, and that caused the crashed, as some of them request for files the Windows way.

Sorry!